# 6 by 6 Array Validation

Tags: java, arrays

[image: tinypic.com/r/e5fy4j/8]

What I'm trying to do with my code is ensure you can only click squares that are touching where the user initially clicks, meaning here that only the buttons touching the 5 should be able to be clicked on (in this case: 4,4,4,2,8,1,6,0)

The background information for this is that it's a [6][6] array of buttons.
You shouldn't be able to  click (/won't color and add scores to) any buttons that aren't touching the one you initially click and as you progress through the game.

Comment: Post the relevant part of your code. Using correct Java syntax.  And explain what result you expect and what you actually get. Also seeing that you use IDE - debug your code step-by-step to see how exactly your logic works.

Comment: Since you seem to be new to the site, you may want to review the following [help post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your `valid()` method should be like following:

```
//loop-start

    if (condition is satified) return true;

// loop-end

return false;
```

In Java (unlike VB) you cannot assign values to methods.  You cannot instantiate a method as well.

Comment: Please re-check my question :), as I tried that previously.

Comment: @user3574877  - not in the code you posted earlier.

Comment: Oh yeah, I tried doing it and I posted it, still isn't working. I can post more code if that'd be beneficial :)?

Comment: Post the relevant (compilable) code and explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: code added, the code added adds the buttons

Comment: @user3574877 - Do not see it. BTW, your question already got 3 "close" votes, so unless you improve it right away it will be put on hold.